# Отрисовка квадратов на системе координат

Tags: javascript, html, вёрстка, геометрия

Не знаю с чего начать, подскажите как по заданным точкам отрисовать 2 квадрата на системе, https://gist.github.com/nexusloh/b5eeeb49b46e94155f40ff9bd805da97 мой код. У меня есть система, есть 8 инпутов для точек, подскажите, что дальше.

Comment: Конечно код нужен, а то вы не вопрос задаете а хотите что бы за вас всю работу сделали. Дайте код и конкретно объясните вашу проблему.
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: Берете значения из этих полей ввода. Смотрите координаты левого верхнего угла, вычисляете длину сторон по x и y осям, вычитая из правого нижнего левые верхние координаты. Потом используете canvas или SVG. Там уже есть функция, принимающие координаты левого верхнего угла и длину сторон, и возвращающая rectangle. Все просто.
Canvas - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/%D0%A0%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80
SVG - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82/rect